# How to create database connection as instance of instance of Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface in Illuminate library?

Tags: php, laravel, illuminate-container

I am developing a restful application in slim framework. I am using a session manager which uses database library of illuminate. It requires me to create a  database connection using instance of Laravel's illuminate. But I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'lib/vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'lib/init.php';
require 'lib/Slim/Slim.php';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

use lib\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie;

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim([
    // cookie encryption (strongly recommend)
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'put your secret key',
    // session config
    'sessions.driver' => 'database', // or database
    //'sessions.files' => __DIR__ . '/../sessions', // require mkdir
    'sessions.table' => 'sessions', // require create table
]);

$manager = new \Slim\Middleware\SessionManager($app);
$session = new \Slim\Middleware\Session($manager);

$manager->setDbConnection(mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database'));

$app->add($session); 

$app->run();
```

This is the error I get:

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface, resource given

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can review the source code for \Illuminate\Database here:
https://github.com/illuminate/database

Taylor has done a great job at providing documentation for using this module independently and creating a Database connection.use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

```
$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! @Jaw.sh Can you please guide me a bit about how do I actually attach $capsule connection to my $manager in this statement in my app: $manager->setDbConnection(mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database'));

Comment: I would assume so. Did you try it?

Comment: There is actually something weird happening, as soon as I put my $capsule->addConnection , my application stops responding even with my correct database details.

Comment: It definitely exists. Make sure that `Capsule` is defined correct. It points to `\Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager`. https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Capsule/Manager.php#L111-L125

Comment: yes its defined perfectly as shown by you and correct as in documentation. It points to \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager. Only when I put the addConnection command, my whole application stops reponding. I think your answer should be correct from what i can tell but not sure though. If only you can tell me this, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: If the application stops responding that typically means it's waiting for MySQL to respond and then gives up.

Comment: But its doing it even if I do it with empty array as: $capsule->addConnection();

Comment: Because it's still trying to connect, but it's trying to connect with only default parameters. I am very certain your issue is incorrect credentials.

Comment: I have checked my credentials over and over again and they are correct. But I do appreciate your efforts and will mark it as correct. Justincase, i have posted it as a separate question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967860/illuminate-library-capsule-object-not-accepting-addconnection-command Incase you find out something, please do let me know. I shall be very thankful.