# Illuminate library capsule object not accepting 'addConnection' command

Tags: php, mysql, illuminate-container

I am developing an application in Slim framework using Illuminate library. I am trying to create a connection to the database using Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager. Some how, it isnt recognizing the 'addConnection' statement. Here is my full code. If anyone can point out where I am going wrong, that would be very helpful.

```
require 'lib/vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'lib/init.php';
require 'lib/Slim/Slim.php';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

use lib\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie;

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();


use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;


$capsule->addConnection(array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'mydatabase',
    'username'  => 'myusername',
    'password'  => 'mypassword',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
));

use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();

$app->run();
```

This is where the script stops and the application goes into 'not responding' state.

> $capsule->addConnection(array(
>           'driver'    => 'mysql',
>           'host'      => 'localhost',
>           'database'  => 'mydatabase',
>           'username'  => 'myusername',
>           'password'  => 'mypassword',
>           'charset'   => 'utf8',
>           'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
>           'prefix'    => '',
>       ));

I have checked my database details over and over again and they are 100% correct. Can anyone point out what might be causing it?

**UPDATE:**

After testing, I have come to realize that the page is giving error http 500 on any wrong statement. For example, if I forget to put a semicolon at the end of the statement, it goes into 500. This suggests that the error might be something else other than SQL. Is there any way to enable debugging so it shows me the cause of error. I might be able to track it down from there?

**UPDATE**

I have enabled debugging. It gives me the following error:

> Call to undefined function Illuminate\Support\value()

Comment: Well seems you are calling 'value()' function, but it does not exist? Strange thing.

Maybe you are including illuminate support manually and helper file is not auto_included? Try to add this file to composer autoload files list

Answer (score 2):

"goes into 'not responding' state."
this seems more like 'not responding' from MySQL server. I would vote for invalid hostname. Try changing localhost with 127.0.0.1. Also (if supported) it is better to use mysqli (instead of mysql driver).

Because if it freezes for ~30-60 seconds, it is timeout settings before you get any timeout error. Do you get any?

Also, for 'fresh' examples of Eloquent usage, you can find here: https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch (if you are using laravel 4.2 you should switch branch to 4.2 for older examples)

Comment: After testing, I have come to realize that the page is giving error http 500 on any wrong statement. For example, if I forget to put a semicolon at the end of the statement, it goes into 500. This suggests that the error might be something else other than SQL. Is there any way to enable debugging so it shows me the cause of error. I might be able to track it down from there?

Comment: Do you want to have a look at the second update please?

Comment: About debugging. I have some problems (to be honest) with nginx. It sometimes just DON'T SHOW ERROR. And I see only - 500 error. In these situations I just navigate to /var/log/nginx/....error log for that vhost and see the logs.)
Other thing is, that I ofter just do: tail -f /var/log/nginx/domain.app-errors.log - so when developing I see errors instantly when they come up!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing to include **Illuminate\Support\helpers.php** where the function **value()** is defined as this

```
if (! function_exists('value')) {
    /**
     * Return the default value of the given value.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    function value($value)
    {
        return $value instanceof Closure ? $value() : $value;
    }
}
```